# Is there an easy way to compute the intersection of two different indexes in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, if I have a DataFrame consisting of 5 rows (0-4) and 5 columns (A-E), I want to say, 0A * E3.  Or more pseudo-like df[0,A] * df[3,E]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need select values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then multiple:

```
a = df.loc[0,'A'] * df.loc[3,'E']
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  8  8  3  7  7
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8
3  4  0  9  6  2
4  4  1  5  3  4

a = df.loc[0,'A'] * df.loc[3,'E']
print (a)
16
```

Btw, your pseodo code is very close to real solution.

Comment: Well, that was easy enough.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad can help! Nice weekend!